# What are the value ranges for uint8 CIE Luv Mat?

Tags: python, c++, opencv

In OpenCV, I am working with a `cv::Mat` that is in the colour space CIE Luv and the Mat data type is uint8.

I am trying to figure out the value ranges for each channel. Is the below correct?

> L  can be any value from 0-255
>   U  can be any value from 0-255
>   V  can be any value from 0-255

I am aware that in OpenCV HSV Mats can be the following (note hue doesn't use the whole value range). So I'd like to know what CIE Luv uses aswell.

> H  can be any value from 0-180
>   S  can be any value from 0-255
>   V  can be any value from 0-255

Answer (score 1):

For `uint8`:

**HSV: (0,0,0) ~ (180,255, 255)**

**LUV: (0,0,0) ~ (255, 255, 255)**

The following is taken from 
https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html

---

[image]

---

[image]